# 'Error: unable to verify the first certificate' when trying to start discord bot

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I've encountered an error when setting up a discord bot using Visual Studio Code & Node.
This is the code that makes the bot go online:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.login('[the token i recieved for my bot]');
```

The error I get from running this is:

```
(node:7064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: unable to verify the first certificate    warning.js:18
 at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
 at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
 at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8)
(node:7064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
 by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not
 handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)    warning.js:18
(node:7064) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future,
 promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.    warning.js:18
```

Can anyone help me debug this or not get this error?

Comment: What do you mean by _using Visual Studio Code_? Are you just using it to code the bot or you're running it via some plugin or package inside Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your error, using the exact same setup.

> `discord.js: v11.4.2` and `Visual Studio Code: v1.28.2`

If you still experience this issue, [maybe this can help you](https://www.codingdefined.com/2016/03/solved-error-unable-to-verify-first.html).